# Matplotlib plotting data that doesnt exist

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot three lines on one figure. I have data for three years for three sites and i am simply trying to plot them with the same x axis and same y axis. The first two lines span all three years of data, while the third dataset is usually more sparse. Using the object-oriented axes matplotlib format, when i try to plot my third set of data, I get points at the end of the graph that are out of the range of my third set of data. my third dataset is structured as tuples of dates and values such as:

```
data=
[('2019-07-15', 30.6),
 ('2019-07-16', 20.88),
 ('2019-07-17', 16.94),
 ('2019-07-18', 11.99),
 ('2019-07-19', 13.76),
 ('2019-07-20', 16.97),
 ('2019-07-21', 19.9),
 ('2019-07-22', 25.56),
 ('2019-07-23', 18.59),
 ...
 ('2020-08-11', 8.33),
 ('2020-08-12', 10.06),
 ('2020-08-13', 12.21),
 ('2020-08-15', 6.94),
 ('2020-08-16', 5.51),
 ('2020-08-17', 6.98),
 ('2020-08-18', 6.17)]
```

where the data ends in August 2020, yet the graph includes points at the end of 2020. This is happening with all my sites, as the first two datasets stay constant `knowndf['DATE']` and `knowndf['Value']` below.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQD9C.png) is the problematic graph.

And here is what I have for the plotting:

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,12)) 
fig.tight_layout(pad=6) 

ax.plot(knowndf['DATE'], knowndf['Value1'],'b',alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(knowndf['DATE'], knowndf['Value2'],color='red',alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(*zip(*data), 'g*', markersize=8) #when i plot this set of data i get nonexistent points
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45) #rotating for aesthetic 
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::30]) #only want every 30th tick instead of every daily tick
```

I've tried `ax.twinx()` and that gives me two y axis that doesn't help me since i want to use the same x-axis and y-axis for all three sites. I've tried not using the axes approach, but there are things that come with axes that i need to plot with. Please please help!

Comment: The dates in your data array are strings.  Convert to datetime and you should find it works better

Comment: @JodyKlymak this did work, but now my first two datasets are connecting improperly in matplotlib, but this helped. Thanks